# Symfony and Encore print css in page for critical path

Tags: symfony, webpack-encore

Is it possible to print the css in the page instead of generating link tags with `{{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}` ? Or is there another solution to integrate the critical path?

Answer (score 1):

I can't add a comment because of low reputation, however take a look at [symfonycasts](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/mailer/encore-inline_css)
There is whole solution presented.

Basically you should parse *entrypoints.json* file, find proper css files which you need. You can use `EntrypointLookupInterface` for that. Then get content for that files and return it to the template by nice own twig extension.

```php
class AppExtension extends AbstractExtension implements ServiceSubscriberInterface
{

    private $publicDir;
    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container, string $publicDir)
    {
        $this->publicDir = $publicDir;
    }

    public function getFunctions(): array
    {
        return [
            new TwigFunction('encore_entry_css_source', [$this, 'getEncoreEntryCssSource']),
        ];
    }

    public function getEncoreEntryCssSource(string $entryName): string
    {
        $files = $this->container
            ->get(EntrypointLookupInterface::class)
            ->getCssFiles($entryName);
        $source = '';
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $source .= file_get_contents($this->publicDir.'/'.$file);
        }
        return $source;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedServices()
    {
        return [
            EntrypointLookupInterface::class,
        ];
    }
}
```

You have to also add publicDir to your `config/services.yaml` file

```yaml
services:
    _defaults:
        bind:
            string $publicDir: '%kernel.project_dir%/public'
```

Then in twig template

```
{% apply inky_to_html|inline_css(encore_entry_css_source('email')) %}
{% endapply %}
```